# Getting the sum of the values of the properties of an object

Tags: javascript-objects

I'm looking to take the result of a survey that I created using JSON, add up the values associated with the objects from that survey in order to produce a sum. However, I am unsure of how to call upon the items within the `Survey Result`

I would apprecaite any help.

```
Survey Result: {
   "Number of Polarization Images":1,
   "Possibility of Primes":2,
   "Available Layers":2,
   "Image Quality":3,
   "Lead Rank":3,
   "Repairs Report":2,
   "Topography":2,
   "AOI Size":1,
   "Field Verification":2,
   "Season":1
}
```

Comment: Which language are you coding in?

Comment: I'm using http://surveyjs.org/index.html

The syntax seems to be JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.reduce` combined with `Object.values` for browsers that support it

```
var sum = Object.values( survey_results_variable ).reduce((p,v)=>p+v,0);
```

For browsers that do not support `Object.values` use `Object.keys`

```
var sum = Object.keys( survey_results ).reduce((p,v)=>p+survey_results[v],0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is

```
var sum = 0;  
for (k in survey_result) sum += survey_result[k];
```

The bit you might have been missing was the [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) way of iterating over properties in an object.